# Startup image not updating on installed ios webapp

Tags: iphone, ios, web-applications, ios6

I have my web app installed on my device, the app can be updated changing the cache.manifest, everything changes except the startup image, this image cannot be updated when the app its already installed?

I know that the new image works because when I "install" (add to home screen) a new instance of the webapp it has the updated image!

Tested only on iOS 6.1 / iPhone 5

**Updated:**

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/img_splash.jpg" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/img_splash.jpg" media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" />
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add code showing how you call/show the startup image?

Comment: post updated with your request...

Comment: Once the app is cache on iOS device and you change img_splash.jpg to img_splash01.jpg; update the cache.manifest, are you saying iOS doesn't load the new img_splash01.jpg?

Comment: no, maybe when the app is installed, use the the current set image and don't change it when the app is updated

Answer (score 1):

To force the update, you will could change the startup image file name also.

Force Update Steps:

1. Place new startup image on web server with new name
2. Update the HTML5 page or javascript file to reference the new name
3. Update cache.manifest with new name
4. Profit...

Comment: still the old image, seems that apple don't let you change the startup image of an "installed" webapp...

Comment: the startup image its only for ios devices (dunno if works on android devices too) when webapp its "installed"